# Program returning garbage after array formed in function

Tags: c++

This program is supposed to use a function to gather 4 grades into an array, use another function to average the grades, and another function to display the average and 4 original grades.

The 4 grades have to be between 0 and 100.

I have this program printing out grade[2] just to test it, but it always outputs garbage. 
What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

Also, if I try to call getGrades(grade, 5) without the "float grade[5]" line in there first, it tells me that "grade" is an undeclared identifier. Which leads me to believe i've done something wrong in writing that function.

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float computeAverage(float exam1, float exam2, float exam3, float exam4)
{
    float average;
    average = exam1*.2 + exam2*.2 + exam3*.2 + exam4*.4;
    return average;
}

void getGrades(float a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    float num;
    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        cin >> num;
        if (num>=0 && num <=100)
            num = a[i];
        else 
        {
            cout << "That number is out of range.";
            i--;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{

float grade[5];

getGrades(grade,5);

grade[4] = computeAverage(grade[0], grade[1], grade[2], grade[3]);

cout << grade[2];






    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not storing the values in `grade` array in `getGrades` function that is the reason you are getting **garbage** value.

Change this:-

```
num = a[i];
```

to

```
a[i] = num;
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks! It's always the simple things.

Answer (score 0):

```
num = a[i];
```

should be

```
a[i] = num;
```

Welcome to computer science :-)